# Connecting multiple databases

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I would like to connect my application with 2 different databases. This is what I have tried:

```java
public class DataSourceWilaConfig {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.wila")
    public DataSource wila() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
}

public class DataSourceWaldConfig {
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.wald")
    public DataSource wald() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
}
```

And so in application.properties I have added:

```
spring.datasource.url=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=

spring.wald.datasource.url=
spring.wald.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.wald.datasource.username=
spring.wald.datasource.password=
```

But Intellij tells me: *Cannot resolve configuration property 'spring.wald.datasource.url'*

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I do notice that your properties look wrong. I assume you want the first one to read spring.wila.datasource.url instead of spring.datasource.url

Comment: @AlexanderKatsenelenbogen `spring.wila.datasource.url ` is set as primary, so `spring.datasource.url ` should be good. The warning that I get only relates to `spring.wald.datasource.url`.

Comment: it might help to change the spring.wald.xxx to wald.xxx (in your application.properties and in the prefix, since the context spring.xx does normally not include spring.wald.

Comment: @Proseller in that case, could you safely remove '@ConfigurationProperties' from that particular bean?

(I know the warning is for wald. The other one just looks a little fishy to me)

Comment: As the others already told you, you should change spring.datasource.* to spring.wila.datasource.*. The warning of IntelliJ just tells you that it doesn't know about your own properties. Please read this https://www.baeldung.com/intellij-resolve-spring-boot-configuration-properties

Comment: @Proseller Yeah -- I'm not convinced by this. I think you need to leave '@ConfigurationProperties' and adjust the prefix to match. The other thing is, I think your prefix needs to be spring.wald.datasource , not spring.wald. Not 100% certain, but ... I would try it.

Comment: @AlexanderKatsenelenbogen I have tried it with all the comments in here and none of them worked for me.

Comment: @Proseller I just notice you don't seem to have '@Configuration' annotations on your classes. Did you leave that out of the post or are they not there in the code?

Comment: @AlexanderKatsenelenbogen thanks for this info. `@Configuration` was missing. I have now added it but I still get the same warning. I have also added the Maven dependency `spring-boot-configuration-processor`, tried to rebuild the project, invalidated cashes and restarted Intellij but the warning still appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of returning `DataSource`, you could return `DataSourceProperties`, like:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class DataSourceWaldConfig {
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.wald")
    public DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class DataSourceWilaConfig {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource.wila")
    public DataSourceProperties wila() {
        return new DataSourceProperties();
    }
}
```

Also, the dependency `spring-boot-configuration-processor` will be required.

**Important:** After that's done, you should rebuild your project.